# Masm32: How do I do collisions in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, masm32

For a project in school I need to make a game using masm32 assembler in visual studio.
I have made a pretty good progress until now, but I have a problem that I couldn't solve: doing collisions.
In the game i built there is some king of a surface\platform that you need to use in order to bump the ball to the basket. the problem is, I can't do the collision right for some reason so the ball goes right through the platform.
Can somebody help me understand what I did wrong?

the code for the collision:

```
ballmovement PROC
    pusha
    mov eax,yball
    cmp eax,ysurf
    jge surfacecollision
    jmp exit
surfacecollision:
    mov eax,xball
    cmp eax,xsurf
    jb exit
    mov ebx,xsurf
    add ebx,240
    cmp eax,ebx
    jg exit
    mov eax, -1
    mov yangle,eax
    jmp exit
exit:
    mov eax,xangle
    add xball,eax
    mov eax,yangle
    add yball,eax
    popa
    ret
ballmovement ENDP
```

The code is supposed to compare the y of the ball to the y of the surface
and than check if the ball is between one side of the surface to the other in the x axis. if so it moves to yangle -1 and than adding it to yball to make the ball go up. the ballmovement proc is always active through a loop in the main proc. in the loop is also a command to redraw the ball in x:xball y:yball
can somebody help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Add all definitions of "variables" too, just to verify you have enough memory allocated, and this is not hunting some memory overwrite.

Comment: And the code looks ok, it can be a bit simplified, and you should decide whether the coordinates are signed or unsigned (`jb exit` is unsigned "below", `jg exit` is signed "greater"), but for most of the cases this should work as is, so rather run it in debugger and see yourself, why the test fails (probably init the ball and surface position in such way, that it will collide in the very first call).

Answer (score 3):

A bit cleaned up version of your code (notice how I'm using label names and comments to make it easier to read through the code and understand how it works). "Fixes" are: all values and comparisons are signed now,`pusha/popa` avoided for performance reasons, the code does use `eax` only now.

But these do NOT explain while you experience the ball not colliding with the surface, your bug is probably elsewhere.

```
ballmovement PROC
    push eax
    mov  eax, [yball]
    cmp  eax, [ysurf]
    jl   do_move    ; ball is above surface (yball < ysurf)
    mov  eax, [xball]
    sub  eax, [xsurf]
    jl   do_move    ; ball is ahead of surface (xball < xsurf)
    cmp  eax, 240   ; (xball-xsurf) compare with 240
    jg   do_move    ; ball is beyond surface (xsurf+240 < xball)
    ; set yangle to -1 to make ball go up
    mov  eax, -1
    mov  [yangle], eax
do_move:
    ; adjust [xball, yball] by vector [xangle, yangle]
    mov  eax, [xangle]
    add  [xball], eax
    mov  eax, [yangle]
    add  [yball], eax
    pop  eax
    ret
ballmovement ENDP
```

Answer (score 1):

You should **not** test the Y coordinate when the ball is to the left or to the right of the platform. That does not qualify as a surface collision like your code says. The order of testing is important here!

> ```
> mov eax,yball
> cmp eax,ysurf
> jge surfacecollision
> ```

If this `cmp` gives the EQ condition, then you're OK. That'll be the optimal starting point to bounce the ball upwards by changing *yangle* to -1.

Problems start when the collision effectively penetrates the surface/platform.
The solution here is to first return the *yball* to *ysurf* and then start moving upward as before.

```
ballmovement PROC
    push    eax
    mov     eax, xsurf
    cmp     xball, eax
    jb      exit
    add     eax,240
    cmp     xball, ebx
    jg      exit
    mov     eax, ysurf
    cmp     yball, eax
    jl      exit
surfacecollision:
    mov     eax, ysurf          <<<<< Add these
    mov     yball, eax          <<<<< Add these
    mov     yangle, -1
exit:
    mov     eax, xangle
    add     xball, eax
    mov     eax, yangle
    add     yball, eax
    pop     eax
    ret
```